# Can't upload my Firefox OS app to my ZTE Open C

Tags: adb, firefox-os

So, I'm making a game for Firefox OS, and just got my ZTE Open C to test it on. I've been running it on the simulator until now. I uploaded a version of it, and it kinda worked, the accelerometer wasn't working for some reason, but that's not the problem. After I installed some apps and updated the OS, I went back to try a newer version of the program, and it won't upload. I press the "Update" button, and it won't do anything. It still works fine on the simulator, and it does won't upload the old version now too. Help!

Comment: Can you give some more details?  Does the phone show up in the app manager or when using adb devices?  What version of Firefox OS does it have installed on it?

Comment: It shows up on the app manager, everything works except this. It's running firefox os 1.3.

Comment: Tried on my laptop, same thing. Also tried firefox nightly, my phone dosn't even show up on nightly.

Comment: From the command line can you type adb shell to see if you can shell into the phone?

Comment: You may also want to look at the troubleshooting section on this page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox_OS/Using_the_App_Manager  Specifically try setting extensions.adbhelper@mozilla.org.sdk.console.logLevel to all

Comment: I'm not running Linux, so I don't think I can shell into the phone... and the troubleshooting section doesn't have anything for this issue.

Comment: you can run a terminal from Mac or Dos Shell from Windows.  The log is to see if ADB Helper is communicating any errors.